# User not saving to firestore collection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to register user to the app using firebase and firestore but nothing goes to the collection. It does create an user but no colleection is ever created. When I try to login I noticed this in the console. I am wondering now if I have a mistake somewhere is there a problem with the navigation stack and why doesn't the users collection is created?

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.19.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds. This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
>
> [Tue Aug 25 2020 12:57:48.133]  ERROR    The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Home","params":{"user":{"id":"4Foqi2I28cTIosFxwnYNmPHD2g53","email":"tester@gmail.com","fullName":"Jukka"}}} was not handled by any navigator.

This is my config

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import '@firebase/auth';
import '@firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'exAMPLE',
  authDomain: 'example.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://example.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'example-af234',
  storageBucket: 'example.appspot.com',
  appId: 'example',
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.firestore();
}

export { firebase };
```

And register code is following.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Image, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View, ToastAndroid , Alert} from 'react-native';
import {KeyboardAwareScrollView} from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import styles from './RegisterStyle';
import { firebase } from '../../firebase/config'

export default function RegistrationScreen({navigation}) {
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');

  const onFooterLinkPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Login');
  };

  const onRegisterPress = () => {
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      ToastAndroid.show("Passwords does not match!", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      return
    }

    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((response) => {
        const uid = response.user.uid
        const data = {
          id: uid,
          email,
          fullName
        }
        const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
        usersRef
          .doc(uid)
          .set(data)
          .then(() => {
            navigation.navigate('Home', {user: data})
          })
      })

  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        style={{flex: 1, width: '100%'}}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
        <Image
          style={styles.logo}
          source={require('../../../assets/icon.png')}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Full Name"
          placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
          onChangeText={(text) => setFullName(text)}
          value={fullName}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="E-mail"
          placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
          onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
          value={email}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
          secureTextEntry
          placeholder="Password"
          onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
          value={password}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
          secureTextEntry
          placeholder="Confirm Password"
          onChangeText={(text) => setConfirmPassword(text)}
          value={confirmPassword}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => onRegisterPress()}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Create account</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.footerView}>
          <Text style={styles.footerText}>
            Already got an account?{' '}
            <Text onPress={onFooterLinkPress} style={styles.footerLink}>
              Log in
            </Text>
          </Text>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

And login is

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Image, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View, ToastAndroid} from 'react-native';
import {KeyboardAwareScrollView} from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import styles from './LoginStyle';
import { firebase } from '../../firebase/config'

export default function LoginScreen({navigation}) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const onFooterLinkPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Registration');
  };

  const onLoginPress = () => {
    firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((response) => {
        const uid = response.user.uid
        const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
        usersRef
            .doc(uid)
            .get()
            .then(firestoreDocument => {
                if (!firestoreDocument.exists) {
                  ToastAndroid.show("User does not exist anymore.", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
                  return;
                }
                const user = firestoreDocument.data()
                navigation.navigate('Home', {user})
            })
    })
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        style={{flex: 1, width: '100%'}}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
        <Image
          style={styles.logo}
          source={require('../../../assets/icon.png')}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="E-mail"
          placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
          onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
          value={email}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
          secureTextEntry
          placeholder="Password"
          onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
          value={password}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => onLoginPress()}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Log in</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.footerView}>
          <Text style={styles.footerText}>
            Don't have an account?{' '}
            <Text onPress={onFooterLinkPress} style={styles.footerLink}>
              Sign up
            </Text>
          </Text>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hello, It looks like this is a somewhat common issue in firestore and there are some issues with this problem in their github page. It looks like the problem could be caused by authorization issues or due to restrictions, I believe this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3763) could help you solving this issue.

Comment: I had a look there but I didn't understand it. @LuisManuel

Comment: So, as far as I understand both issues, firestore sends the "Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds" error when there are issues with either the connectivity of your device (or simulator where you run your tests) and the endpoint from cloud firestore. In the case of the issue that I shared with you this was caused by the API restriction settings for iOS. But this could have a lot of causes, but the issue is already delimited that this is happening as the request is not getting to the endpoint, I would suggest to verify the API restrictions and ->

Comment: the requests that you are sending to the back end, as this is what is causing the error (or at least this is what the error is telling us and also based on other issues from github, we can notice that this can also be caused by SSL configurations from your requests but your need to analyze the requests that you are doing in order to find out what is blocking your app)